# Remove Non-ASCII but not one specific character

Tags: regex, excel, non-ascii-characters

Current: I have a function that removes all non-ascii characters:
[^\x20-\x7F] in excel from strings, which works!

Needed: a function removing non-ascii characters but not char(10) (line breaks). I though regular expression supports negated locality so my proposal was ([^\x20-\x7F]+/n).

However, in this form it does not remove any non-ascii characters (but maintains the line breaks).

Comment: Can you show some sample data? And exactly which ascii chars would you want to have removed?

Answer (score 0):

This will retain characters with ASCII codes between 20<sub>16</sub> and 7F<sub>16</sub> as well as A<sub>16</sub>:

```
Public Function Kleanup(sIn As String) As String
    Dim temp As String, L As Long, i As Long, CH As String

    temp = ""
    L = Len(sIn)
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(sIn, i, 1)
        If (Asc(CH) > 31 And Asc(CH) < 128) Or CH = Chr(10) Then
            temp = temp & CH
        End If
    Next i

    Kleanup = temp
End Function
```